# How to cancel firestore calls in web v9?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a `React`, firestore app. The app gets data from firestore and displays it in a table. The fetching of the data is done in a `useEffect` as can be seen below.

```
export default DisplayPage() {
  const [records,setRecord] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const docRef = doc(db, 'table_name');
      return getDoc(docRef);
    }
    getData().then(data => setRecord(data.data()))
    return () => {
        // implement cancel call here?
    }

  })
  // table display here ...
}
```

It works all fine and good but the problem I have here is how do I cancel the firestore calls.

As soon as I visit the page the API calls are called but even if I navigate back to a page before the calls are completed, the API calls keep continuing until they've finished.

I know fetch has `AbortController` and so does `Axios` but I was unable to find anything for Firestore calls. I have seen it for onSnapshot listens but upon reading the docs for normal firestore get calls there aren't any options for cancelling the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to cancel a `get()` call that has already started. The best I can think of is to detect that the component has gone out of scope, and not calling `setRecord` when that has already happened.

Upon a quick search, that's precisely what the answer here shows: [How to stop Firestore `get` query on componentWillUnmount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52524368/how-to-stop-firestore-get-query-on-componentwillunmount)

Also see:

- [Can I cancel a Firestore write? (using offline persistence)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50454135/can-i-cancel-a-firestore-write-using-offline-persistence)
- [How to unsubscribe the Firestore fetching data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979393/how-to-unsubscribe-the-firestore-fetching-data)